# How would I take data from an Excel tab and create a list for use in a Classify function?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to do the following:

1. Load data from a single tab of an Excel workbook into a Mathematica table.
2. Prepare the data for use with the Mathematica `Classify` function.

The training set that I want to pass into Classify would be:

```
 xlData = Import["TrainingData.xlsx"];
```

I am using a Table function to generate the list of associations to pass to the `Classify` function.

```
cfList:=Table[{xlData[[1]][[row]][[1]], 
               xlData[[1]][[row]][[2]],
               xlData[[1]][[row]][[3]]}->xlData[[1]][[row]][[5]],
               {row, 1, 5}];
```

Several things I have noticed here.

- If I dump `cfList` by just typing it on an input line, *Mathematica* gets very bogged down.  After 30 to 50 seconds some output finally appears.
- If I execute `Classify[cfList];`, it take at least 2 minutes on as few as 10 items in `cfList`.

My primary question is: what is the best way to build a list of associations from Excel data for use with the Classify function?

Comment: Data from excel, when imported, appears as lists of lists. Have you just tried making a simple excel file and then working out what depth of list you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry Hugh, I am working with a simple Excel file.  The depth of the list is not the question.  I am asking how I would prepare data from an Excel sheet for use with the Classify function.

Comment: Does it work for you? `{#, #2, #3} -> #7 & @@@ 
 Rest(*dropheaders*)@First(*sheet*)@Import[pathToXLSX]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an excel file to try and replicate your inputs.  Row 1 is comprised of headers.  In columns A through C I have trial data.  In Column G, I have an "Answer" that the data should be pointing to.

First, Import your data:

```
data = Import["TrainingData.xlsx"]
```

Then separate out your inputs from your answers:

```
inputs = data[[1, All, 1 ;; 3]] // Rest
answers = data[[1, All, 7]] // Rest
```

Then thread the two together for your classify function:

```
thread = Thread[inputs -> answers]
```

Now you can run the `Classify` function on it:

```
classify = Classify[thread]
```

And pull the results based on new inputs:

```
classify[{7, 62, 52}]
```

NOTE: The above assumes that columns A, B, and C are numbers, but this should work with anything.